# Why am I unable to access props from vue root inside components template?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to access job_execs from the stage-execs component in the template...

job_execs is created in the vue root and I am trying to access it by calling it in the props of the stage-execs component.

```
<div id="vue-job">
<div class="column">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>test</h3>
        <stage-execs></stage-execs>
    <br><br>
</div>
</div>


<script>
    Vue.component('stage-execs', {
        delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
        props: ['job_execs'],
        data: function() {
                return {
                    job_execs: job_execs
                }
            },
        template: `
        <ul id="example-1">
          <li v-for="item in job_execs">
            [[ item.build_id ]]
          </li>
        </ul>
        `,
    });

    var v_root = new Vue({
        delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
        el: '#vue-job',
        data: {
            job_execs: []
        },
        created() {
            url="http://{{ api_endpoint }}"
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(body => {
                    for(i=0; i<body.length; i++){
                        this.job_execs.push({
                            'build_id': JSON.stringify(body[i].build_id),
                            'status': JSON.stringify(body[i].status.name),
                        })
                    }
            })
            .catch( err => {
                console.log('Error Fetching:', url, err);
                return { 'failure': url, 'reason': err };
            });

        },
    });
```

What is the correct way here to access job_execs in the stage-execs component?

Comment: Any news? Did you manage to resolve this?  Did my example help or are you still stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VueJS, you always pass data from the parent (root in your case) to the component (stage-execs component) with props.

So to answer your question

> What is the correct way here to access job_execs in the stage-execs
>   component?

The answer is: With a prop. Define a prop on your component and pass down a value from the parent.

In your component you defined the props job_execs, but you didn't pass anything down.

```
<stage-execs></stage-execs>
```

It is missing it's prop. So your html should be:

```
<div id="vue-job">
<div class="column">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>test</h3>
        <stage-execs :job_execs="job_execs"></stage-execs>
    <br><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Notice the difference in the component.

I bind the job_execs props on your component to the data property job_execs in your root. Please note that the `: job_execs=` is the equavalent of `v-bind:job_execs=` and is a reference to your props on your component. The value passed down is the data property from your root. Sorry if I am be overstaitng things, I'm just trying to avoid confusion since the prop on the component and the data property in root have the same name.

In your component there's no need to make a data property named job_execs and in fact you should never name your data properties and props the same name. See: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/questions-regarding-handling-immutable-props-and-mutable-data-props/967/2?u=tarasovych

So now our code looks like

```
Vue.component('stage-execs', {
    delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
    props: ['job_execs'],        
    template: `
    <ul id="example-1">
      <li v-for="item in job_execs">
        [[ item.build_id ]]
      </li>
    </ul>
    `,
});
```

Since I passed a value to the props. I can now iterate through it.

I've made a working example on codepen: https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/eaPdyv

In that example I've just manually entered some dummy value for the array.

Answer (score 0):

remove this part:

```
data: function() {
     return {
         job_execs: job_execs
     }
}
```

and update the template with:

```
<ul id="example-1">
    <li v-for="item in this.job_execs">
        {{ item.build_id }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: job_execs still doesnt return anything in the component template and in vue dev tool it shows props job_execs: undefined

Comment: Did you add property to <stage-execs /> subcomponent in your root component, it should look like this <stage-execs : job_execs =['Job 1', 'Job 2']></stage-execs>